# Literal Type inference - Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, dynamic-typing

considering this definition:

```js
interface Domain<Model, Name extends string> {
  name: Name;
  edit(cb: (m: Model) => Model): Domain<Model, Name>;
}

declare function createDomain<
  M extends { [key: string]: any } = {},
  N extends string = string
>(name: N): Domain<M, N>;
```

the IDE is able to give you correct inspection (as shown in figure):
[image]
this because *typescript* is able to infer **`'foo'`** as literal type which **`extends N /* string */`**.

#### but

if I provide a signature for the generic `M`, then typescript looses the information about `'foo'` and returns a generic `string`.
[image]

how can I change the above definition to preserve the information about `N`?

Answer (score 2):

I see these options:

**Provide the second type**

```
let domain = createDomain<Todo, "foo">("foo");
```

**Build a factory**

```
function funcCreateDomain<M>() {
    return <N extends string>(name: N) => createDomain<M, N>(name);
}

let factory = funcCreateDomain<Todo>();
let domain = factory("foo");
```

Comment: unfortunately changing the surface api is not an option and manually providing the literal type looks redundant.